# Floating Bitmaps, Coding Conflicts?

Tags: java, wear-os, centering, watch

Good day, I am beginning to learn Java and one of the first projects that I thought might help me to begin learning is by designing a watch face for WearOS, I am an artist/illustrator (currently going back to school to learn computer programming) by birth and school, so I am currently attempting work that I have some idea about.

My question is this. I have designed and implemented bitmaps that are rotating for the watch's hands, and have tried to center them with "mCenterX and Y" and have even manually tried to center them with canvas.translate, and entering in coordinates. Sorry if this is an absolute newbie question, but I have been Googling and attempting for at least a week. (Would include image of floating hands, but can't embed.)

The "Hour Hand" is the only one that I have currently working, and I only was able to do that with manually entering the coordinates with canvas.translate. The other hands will come into frame every-once-in-a-while then float out of frame, rotating around some "unknown" center point.

Code is below: (I have included all code pertaining to the bitmaps for the hour/minute/second hands, to see if I have something that is conflicting. I am using bits of code from various projects, which probably explains the off-centeredness, but I don't have the knowledge yet to grasp why, which is my ultimate goal here.)

Thank you for looking and replying! If you need additional information, let me know.

```
 private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
        private static final float HOUR_STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float MINUTE_STROKE_WIDTH = 3f;
        private static final float SECOND_TICK_STROKE_WIDTH = 2f;

        private static final float CENTER_GAP_AND_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 4f;

        private static final int SHADOW_RADIUS = 6;
        /* Handler to update the time once a second in interactive mode. */
        private final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new EngineHandler(this);
        private Calendar mCalendar;
        private final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                invalidate();
            }
        };
        private boolean mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;
        private boolean mMuteMode;
        private float mCenterX;
        private float mCenterY;
private int mWatchHandColor;
        private int mWatchHandHighlightColor;
        private int mWatchHandShadowColor;
        private Paint mHourPaint;
        private Paint mMinutePaint;
        private Paint mSecondPaint;
        private Paint mTickAndCirclePaint;
        private Paint mBackgroundPaint;
        private Bitmap mHourBitmap;
        private Bitmap mMinuteBitmap;
        private Bitmap mSecondBitmap;
        private Bitmap mBackgroundBitmap;
        private Bitmap mGrayBackgroundBitmap;

private void initializeWatchFace() {
            /* Set defaults for colors */
            mWatchHandColor = Color.WHITE;
            mWatchHandHighlightColor = Color.RED;
            mWatchHandShadowColor = Color.BLACK;

            mHourPaint = new Paint();
            mHourPaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
            mHourPaint.setStrokeWidth(HOUR_STROKE_WIDTH);
            mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mHourPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mHourPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);

            mMinutePaint = new Paint();
            mMinutePaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
            mMinutePaint.setStrokeWidth(MINUTE_STROKE_WIDTH);
            mMinutePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mMinutePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mMinutePaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);

            mSecondPaint = new Paint();
            mSecondPaint.setColor(mWatchHandHighlightColor);
            mSecondPaint.setStrokeWidth(SECOND_TICK_STROKE_WIDTH);
            mSecondPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mSecondPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mSecondPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);

            mTickAndCirclePaint = new Paint();
            mTickAndCirclePaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
            mTickAndCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(SECOND_TICK_STROKE_WIDTH);
            mTickAndCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mTickAndCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mTickAndCirclePaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
        }

 private void updateWatchHandStyle() {
            if (mAmbient) {
                mHourPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                mMinutePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                mSecondPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                mTickAndCirclePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
                mMinutePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
                mSecondPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
                mTickAndCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(false);

                mHourPaint.clearShadowLayer();
                mMinutePaint.clearShadowLayer();
                mSecondPaint.clearShadowLayer();
                mTickAndCirclePaint.clearShadowLayer();

            } else {
                mHourPaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
                mMinutePaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
                mSecondPaint.setColor(mWatchHandHighlightColor);
                mTickAndCirclePaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);

                mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mMinutePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mSecondPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mTickAndCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

                mHourPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
                mMinutePaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
                mSecondPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
                mTickAndCirclePaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
            }

 @Override
        public void onInterruptionFilterChanged(int interruptionFilter) {
            super.onInterruptionFilterChanged(interruptionFilter);
            boolean inMuteMode = (interruptionFilter == WatchFaceService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);

            /* Dim display in mute mode. */
            if (mMuteMode != inMuteMode) {
                mMuteMode = inMuteMode;
                mHourPaint.setAlpha(inMuteMode ? 100 : 255);
                mMinutePaint.setAlpha(inMuteMode ? 100 : 255);
                mSecondPaint.setAlpha(inMuteMode ? 80 : 255);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

 @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);

            /*
             * Find the coordinates of the center point on the screen, and ignore the window
             * insets, so that, on round watches with a "chin", the watch face is centered on the
             * entire screen, not just the usable portion.
             */
            mCenterX = width / 2f;
            mCenterY = height / 2f;

            /*
             * Calculate lengths of different hands based on watch screen size.
             */
            mSecondHandLength = (float) (mCenterX * 0.875);
            sMinuteHandLength = (float) (mCenterX * 0.75);
            sHourHandLength = (float) (mCenterX * 0.5);


            /* Scale loaded background image (more efficient) if surface dimensions change. */
            float scale = ((float) width) / (float) mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth();

            mBackgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap,
                    (int) (mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth() * scale),
                    (int) (mBackgroundBitmap.getHeight() * scale), false);

            float scale2 = ((float) width) / (float) mSecondBitmap.getWidth();
            mSecondBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mSecondBitmap,
                    12,
                    222, false);

            float scale3 = ((float) width) / (float) mHourBitmap.getWidth();
            mHourBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mHourBitmap,
                    12,139,false);

            float scale4 = ((float) width) / (float) mMinuteBitmap.getWidth();
            mMinuteBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mMinuteBitmap,
                    12,
                    162, false);

private void drawWatchFace(Canvas canvas) {

            /*
             * Draw ticks. Usually you will want to bake this directly into the photo, but in
             * cases where you want to allow users to select their own photos, this dynamically
             * creates them on top of the photo.
             */
            float innerTickRadius = mCenterX - 10;
            float outerTickRadius = mCenterX;
            for (int tickIndex = 0; tickIndex < 12; tickIndex++) {
                float tickRot = (float) (tickIndex * Math.PI * 2 / 12);
                float innerX = (float) Math.sin(tickRot) * innerTickRadius;
                float innerY = (float) -Math.cos(tickRot) * innerTickRadius;
                float outerX = (float) Math.sin(tickRot) * outerTickRadius;
                float outerY = (float) -Math.cos(tickRot) * outerTickRadius;
                canvas.drawLine(mCenterX + innerX, mCenterY + innerY,
                        mCenterX + outerX, mCenterY + outerY, mTickAndCirclePaint);
            }

            /*
             * These calculations reflect the rotation in degrees per unit of time, e.g.,
             * 360 / 60 = 6 and 360 / 12 = 30.
             */
            final float seconds =
                    (mCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + mCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) / 1000f);
            final float secondsRotation = seconds * 6f;

            final float minutesRotation = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 6f;

            final float hourHandOffset = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 2f;
            final float hoursRotation = (mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 30) + hourHandOffset;

            /*
             * Save the canvas state before we can begin to rotate it.
             */
            canvas.save();

            canvas.rotate(hoursRotation, mCenterX, mCenterY);
            Matrix matrixHour = new Matrix();
            matrixHour.setRotate(0, mCenterX, mCenterY);
            canvas.translate(175, 68);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mHourBitmap, matrixHour, mHourPaint);

            canvas.rotate(minutesRotation - hoursRotation, mCenterX, mCenterY);
            Matrix matrixMinute = new Matrix();
            matrixMinute.setRotate(0, mCenterX, mCenterY);
            canvas.translate(175, -60);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mMinuteBitmap, matrixMinute, mMinutePaint);


            /*
             * Ensure the "seconds" hand is drawn only when we are in interactive mode.
             * Otherwise, we only update the watch face once a minute.
             */
            if (!mAmbient) {
                canvas.rotate(secondsRotation - minutesRotation, mCenterX, mCenterY);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrixHour.setRotate(0, mCenterX, mCenterY);
                canvas.translate(-175,35);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mSecondBitmap, matrix, mSecondPaint);
            }

            /* Restore the canvas' original orientation. */
            canvas.restore();
        }
```